# Navigation structure without using standard Apple Navigation Bars (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, interface-builder

Is it possible to set-up a navigation structure using the Interface Builder, without using the standard Apple navigation bar? I want to apply the actions which open a new View Controller to my own custom buttons.

Is this is not possible, do you guys have a good place where I can start learning to do this without using the interface builder?

Comment: Nothing is wrong? But I don't want to use the standard navigation bar from Apple in my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to embed navigation controller with your root view controller.  For that select your view controller in your storyboard click on editor->embed in->navigationController.

In viewDidload write
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true

have one label of size of navigation bar at the top add a button on it and write following code in it's action method

```
@IBAction func goToNextController(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let second = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as SecondViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
    }
```

here secondViewController is the one which we are pushing

similarly have a label and button at the top in secondViewcontroller and write following cod e in your button's action method

```
![@IBAction func previousButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }][2]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this all over the place! Final question: The popViewControllerAnimated method, does it close the view entirely? Like destroys it so no unnecessary memory is used?

Answer (score 1):

In IB you can change the class for the navigation bar to your own class.

[image]

If you don't use IB you can use `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[MyNavBar class] toolbarClass:nil]`

Comment: That means I can fully customize the navigation bar right?

Comment: That is correct.  You can override drawRect:, add sub views, etc.